# Not able to execute RUN commands in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Contents of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM XYZ
MAINTAINER ABC
RUN echo "hello world"
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

When I try to build an image from this file, I see the following:

> permission denied Removing intermediate container

when docker tries to execute the RUN command

Observations:

- This error is irrespective of the content of the RUN command.
- Removing it ensures the build completes without issues.
- I am able to build from the same docker file and image on another host.
- "docker info" produced similar information on both machines.

How can I debug this further to see what the issue is?

Update (in response to the comments below):

- I have been able to build the same image (and others) on this instance before
- The issue occurred irrespective of the base image used
- The issue was specific to this one instance which is running CentOS
- The user I was logged in as was different from the user the daemon was running as (root)

Assuming the issue may have been because of the user mismatch, I changed to root and tried the command. It went through without issues. Then, I changed back to the original user, removed the image and tried again: it went through again! The original issue is not reproducible anymore.

Comment: Can you build with `docker build --rm=false`?

Comment: What is your base image? Is it specific to that image? or do you see the same error on any image? what is your os? Could not reproduce this error in windows 10.

Comment: seems to me a filesystem permission problem. What is your environment? what user is being used to run docker command and what user is docker daemon running with?

Comment: Folks, thank you. Would you consider adding these as answers instead of comments? I was looking for advice on *how* to debug the issue further and your comments, I think are the answers I was looking for.

Comment: @VivekKodira Non of the above comments are answers - they are suggestions and questions asking you to provide more information.If you have worked this out for yourself based on questions - maybe you should post your own answer to your question to help anyone else with a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @jay I disagree. My question was not what the issue was. It was "how do I debug?"

Comment: @VivekKodira I get that - and none of the comments above answers that question. They are simply a series of questions to find out more from your original question.